# ¿Por qué mi bucle for me reinicia el iterador a cero y no permite que se ejecute correctamente?

Tags: c++, bucle-for, pilas

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio de la universidad, debo hacer una pila y estoy intentando hacer un bucle for con una variable que me cuenta cuantos elementos hay dentro del arreglo de la pila, y justo cuando intento iterarlo, me reinicia la variable a cero y no entiendo porqué...
Lo siguiente es simplemente un método de una clase con el que intento manipular una pila y sacar un elemento dentro del arreglo de punteros llamado pila, el for que se ahí es el que me da problemas y me reinicia la variable cima y me la deja en cero y no me recorre todo como debería

```
void Pila::retirar(int carro) {
string retirado = "";
if (!estaVacio() && existe(carro)){
    string *pilaAuxiliar = new string[tam];
    int cimaAuxiliar = 0;
    for (int i = cima; i > 0; --i) {
        pilaAuxiliar[cimaAuxiliar] = pila[cima];
        cimaAuxiliar++;
        movimientos++;
        retirado = pila[cima];
    }
    cout<<"El " <<retirado <<" salio del parqueadero" <<endl;
} else {
    cout<<"El carro no se encuentra en el parqueadero" <<endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Buen día, ¿En dónde declaras cima y cómo actualizas su valor?

Comment: El post decremento e incremento no tienen ninguna diferencia a un pre decremento o incremento si se ubican al final del `for`. Lo que sea que indiques se ejecutará al terminar el ciclo actual.

Comment: @Mateo si es con tipos nativos, en efecto, no habrá diferencia. Si ya estás trabajando con iteradores u objetos un poco más complejos, entonces sí que pueden llegar a apreciarse mejoras de rendimiento al usar el preincremento frente al postincremento

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, revisando el codigo a fondo encontré el problema por el cual se ponia en cero el iterador del for, gracias por su valioso tiempo.